# node child_process.spawn fails with ENOENT when using chained commands

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScript/Javascript/Node.js, but I have to execute a binary myapp (or myapp.exe on Windows) after I have sourced an environment script myapp_env (run myapp_env.bat on Windows)

```
. myapp_env && myapp
```

or in windows (cmd)

```
myapp_env.bat && myapp.exe
```

I am trying to use spawn:

```
import {exec,spawn} from 'child_process';
import {exists} from 'fs'

let programhome: string = 'C:/SoftwareAG105/Apama';
let envscript: string = programhome + '/bin/apama_env.bat';
let program: string = programhome + '/bin/correlator.exe';

exists(envscript , found => 
       console.log( envscript + (found ? " is there" : " is not there")));
exists(program , found => 
       console.log( program + (found ? " is there" : " is not there")));


try {
    let test = spawn(envscript + ' && ' + program);
    test.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data));
    test.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(data));
    test.on('error', data => console.log('ERROR ' + data));
    test.on('end', data => console.log('END ' + data));
    test.on('exit', data => console.log('Exit ' + data));
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I get an `ENOENT` error which I presume is due to it trying to see whether the entire string exists as a file(?). If I run them individually then it works fine. In both cases the `exists` line will print "is there"....

## Edit

After samuels answer I changed the following lines lines

```
...
import {parse,format,join} from 'path'
...
let programhome: string = join( 'C:' , 'SoftwareAG105', 'Apama' );
let envscript: string = join( programhome ,'bin','apama_env.bat');
let program: string = join(programhome , 'bin' , 'correlator.exe');

exists(envscript , found => console.log( envscript + (found ? " is there" : " is not there")));
exists(program , found => console.log( program + (found ? " is there" : " is not there")));
```

> ERROR Error: spawn C:\SoftwareAG105\Apama\bin\apama_env.bat && 
>   C:\SoftwareAG105\Apama\bin\correlator.exe ENOENT index.js:15
>   C:\SoftwareAG105\Apama\bin\apama_env.bat is there index.js:9
>   C:\SoftwareAG105\Apama\bin\correlator.exe is there

TLDR; So my question is can I chain commands in spawn so that I can source the environment and run the program?

Comment: On your command line did you tried first running them in parallel something like this?
`'/bin/apama_env.bat && /bin/correlator.exe` . There are cases when program does not start when spwaned together

Comment: Also What is nodejs version you are using?

Comment: Yes I ran them manually from logged strings `/bin/apama_env.bat && /bin/correlator.exe` and made sure things were right w.r.t. the paths etc... I'm using node v11.6.0 on windows but will update to 12.x whatever is current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so finally I found the information buried deep in various google posts :

I found that exec would work the way I wanted, but spawn would not, it turns out that for exec a shell is started allowing the chaining to occur.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/

> By default, the spawn function does not create a shell to execute the
>   command we pass into it. This makes it slightly more efficient than
>   the exec function, which does create a shell. The exec function has
>   one other major difference. It buffers the command’s generated output
>   and passes the whole output value to a callback function (instead of
>   using streams, which is what spawn does).

child_process.spawn takes an options object which can have a property called shell

```
let test = spawn(envscript + ' && ' + program,{shell:true});
```

This extra configuration allows me to do the chaining I needed and so I can now source the environment and run the program correctly.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for this, I was getting a `spawn cmd ENOENT` error as well. which was confusing because of cmd being in my env PATH. Didn't realise that the command was not being executed in a shell so no env.

Answer (score 0):

That might have something to do with the path delimiter on Windows being a backslash instead of a forward slash.

When building your strings, try to use [`path.delimiter`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_delimiter) (imported from the default node `path` module) (which is either `/` or `\` depending on the OS). Like so :

```
let programhome: string = ['C:', 'SoftwareAG105', 'Apama'].join(path.delimiter);.
```

This way your path will always be valid, regardless of the OS.

Comment: Hi @Samuel - thanks for this I updated my question to include code that uses this - great tip actually :) - but unfortunately I still get the same issue - If I run individual commands envscript or program individually it works (well it runs) but chained with the '&&' it fails....